# sum of counts. According to the condition

Tags: python, arrays, list

> Given the array nums, for each nums[i] find out how many numbers in the array are smaller than it. That is, for each nums[i] you have to count the number of valid j's such that j != i and nums[j] < nums[i].

Example:

```
Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
output: [4,0,1,1,3]
```

Explain:

```
For nums[0]=8 there exist four smaller numbers than it (1, 2, 2 and 3).
```

My answer is incomplete:

```
class Solution:
    def smallerNumbersThanCurrent(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        return [smth if i> nums[j] else 0 for i in nums for j in range(len(nums))]
```

i cant find the main place instead smth

Result must be sum of counts

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250192/discussion-on-question-by-herzeg-sum-of-counts-according-to-the-condition).

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right that will work for you

```
    def smaller_numbers_than_current(input_list):
        result = []
        for num in input_list:
            result.append(sum(1 for item in input_list if item < num))
        # print(result)
     return sum(result)

   
     if __name__ == '__main__':
         nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
         print(smaller_numbers_than_current(nums))
```